# SDK manager symbol is not available in android studio toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I have installed the android studio on my windows 7 OS. But to install SDK Tools SDK symbol is not present in the toolbar.

Comment: Have you download Android Studio from here : https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: Goto File -> Project Structure -> SDKs have you seen any Android Platform there ?

Comment: Yes, there are 3 platforms, but along with a "?".

Answer (score 0):

Go to window>Restore Default Layout

Or else access sdk manager at

Tools>android>SDK Manager

Another option to completely customize toolbar is

File>Settings  , then under IDE Settings, click on menus and tool bars to customize your own view, select any buttons and change their placement etc. etc.

UPDATE:

If there is no android sdk manager in tools:-

In that case , reinstall Android Studio but Instead of installing using the installer, you could also try to extract the zip from here into a new directory,

http://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/0.8.2/android-studio-ide-135.1267975-windows.zip

and try to run it. Note that this package does not contain the SDK, make sure you copy the SDK folder from your existing installation. to the new installation.

Try it and let us know if it worked

Comment: android>SDK Manager is not present in Tools.:(